# How get this library working under Eclipse - Java Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to use this library in Eclipse for an Android App.

https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss

I read README section, but I can't have it working :(

Can anyone help me? Please

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder called '**libs**' in you project root folder

Copy your external jar library files to the libs folder

Eclipse automatically adds these files to your build path, so you don't need to right click and do *"Add to Build path"* manually.

**EDIT :**
Since there are no external jar files here, you would need to follow a different procedure.

1. Get the source code of the library (using GitTool)
2. Import the android-rss project in your workspace
3. **Right click -> Properties -> Android -> Mark** ***"Is library"*** (this makes the android-rss a library project in your workspace
4. Create your own new project (in which you want to reference this library) and assume that the name is MyTestProject
5. Right Click on MyTestProject -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add (add the android-rss project as the library for MyTestProject)

Comment: No jar here... Plz read the link

Comment: @ingamedeo it's interesting, you chastising someone for not reading your link... surely before posting and asking others to spend time to help you, you must have googled something like "android library in eclipse" (since to not do so would be terribly inconsiderate)... the very first link in that search's results has your answer.

Comment: @mah Ugh... no need to be rude! As you can see on the library page (my link) with this library there are specific issues. I know how to add a library in Eclipse..But I was asking this particular one.

Comment: @swayam Importing library fails with a lot er errors. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @ingamedeo I can appreciate why you feel my comment is rude. It's unfortunate that you do not seem to recognize the level of rudeness within your own question and your expectations of others.

Comment: Well, I don't mean to be rude either. But @ingamedeo, if you want some specific answers, then it is easier if your question is specific, as to what exact errors you are getting. Simply saying *"I can't have it working"* is really helpful.

Comment: Anyway, @ingamedeo could you please mention what errors you are getting while importing

Comment: @swayam A lot of them.. I'd like just to have a working procedure... Can I ask you a thing? It would be really appreciated.. Can you try the procedure on your Eclipse? Does it work? I simply imported the library and ehm...

Comment: Uhhh.. the thing is that I don't have my development system with me right now. So, right now, I can't help you with it. Sorry. :(